# tablesorter text extraction not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am using the absolutely fabulous `tablesorter` plugin to sort my tables.

But(there is always a but), the text extraction that I assigned doesn't seem to work after an AJAX update.

This is how I initialize the plugin:

```
$("table.prices").tablesorter({
    textExtraction: function (node) {
        if (node.innerHTML == "N/A") {
            if (node.className == 'col_14')
                return "10/31/1972";
            else
                return " ";
        }
        else {
            return node.innerHTML;
        }
    },
    cssChildRow: 'index',
    widgets: ['stickyHeaders'],
    cssInfoBlock: "tablesorter-no-sort",
    headers: { /*20: { sorter: 'incept-date'}*/0: { sorter: false }, 1: { sorter: false }, 2: { sorter: false }, 3: { sorter: false }, 4: { sorter: false }, 23: { sorter: false} },
    sortList: [[13, 0]]
});
```

I use text Extraction as I want `N/A(s)` on all column to stay at bottom and sort for the date column.

The problem is, when i update my table with new data, the text `Extraction` doesn't work
This is my AJAX call code:

```
 $.ajax({
            contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "html",
            url: "/AjaxCall.aspx",
            success: function (data) {
                $("table.prices").html(data);
                 $("table.prices")
                    .trigger("update")
                    .trigger("appendCache"); }
        });
```

**Question:** How to get the text extraction to work after the table has been updated new data.

Comment: reinitialize table sorter after adding new elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `if (node.className == 'col_14')` was not true when the data was pulled using ajax.
Tablesorter actually retains all the initialization property after ajax call.

Comment: I have almost the same problem, can you please take a look at my question and see if you can help me out. Thank you so much http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451260/tablesorter-filter-widget-stops-working-after-update-on-all-browsers-no-error-m